# The Golden Calf timeline - hour by hour?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel

I can't figure out how the making of the Calf was possible in a couple of hours:

1. 12pm was the time Moses promised to return. Satan started fooling around, people started to question.
2. The bad guys (presumably thousands of them) gathered together. Some say it was Erev Rav, so they needed to enter Machane Yisroel which was some 10 miles (?).
3. They had some fight with Chur and killed him. That would probably take some time.
4. They went to Aharon which was in Machane Leviyah, also some 3-5 miles from there.
5. They approached Aharon and probably had some negotiation. Aharon decided to make it happen and asked for gold. The bad guys needed to go back to their families talk to their wives and kids, collect all the gold and bring it back to Aharon.
6. When they returned with gold Aharon started to build the Mizbeah which also took some time.
7. Finally he made the fire and throw the gold into the fire.

All those events should have happened presumably before dark in 6 hours. This looks somewhat unrealistic to me, but I might be wrong.

Did anybody make an hour-by-hour timeline of the events in the GC incident?

Comment: There was a Machaneh Leviya already? There wasn't even a Mishkan

Comment: Where do you see that the calves were finished before nightfall? All we know is that it was before they went to sleep. Maybe they stayed up late?

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting, did they straighten up only after the Mishkan was built? How did they travel before? All mixed up?